# How do I get data loaded in an Angular Service into two components at the same time?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-routing

I've got an angular component that loads a client from the database using a service. Rather than keep returning to the database for every component, I am caching this data in the service as the Selected Client.

```
export class ClientService {
  Clients: Client[];

  constructor() {
    this.Clients = [
      {
        client:  0,
        name: "Fred",
        street: "Brockton Drive",
        address1: null,
        address2: null,
        city: "SomewhereVille",
        zipcode: "1234"
        },
        {
          client:  1,
          name: "Wilma",
          street: "Somerset Drive",
          address1: null,
          address2: null,
          city: "Elsewhere",
          zipcode: "0987"
          },
    ]
   }

  setCurrentClient(id: number) {
    var client = this.Clients[id];
    console.log(client);
    this.selectedClient.next(client);

  }

  readonly selectedClient: Subject<Client> = new Subject<Client>()

}
```

Then in the Client component I subscribe to the route parameters, and tell the client service to load the client, and set the selectedClient.

```
export class ClientComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private clientService: ClientService) {
    console.log("order component activated");

      route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
        const cid = params.get("id");
        if (cid)
          clientService.setCurrentClient(Number.parseInt(cid));
        else
          this.selectedClient = undefined;
      })
     clientService.selectedClient.subscribe((data) => this.selectedClient = data)

  }

  selectedClient?: Client;

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

In the Client Details component, I then subscribe to the client service - selected client. This is the part that isn't working. As the details don't get filled out.

```
export class ClientDetailsComponent implements OnDestroy {


  ClientForm: FormGroup;
  token?: Subscription;

  constructor(private clientService: ClientService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

    this.ClientForm = this.formBuilder.group<Client>(new Client());
     this.token = this.clientService.selectedClient.subscribe((data) => {
      this.selectedClient = data;
      this.ClientForm.setValue(this.selectedClient);
      console.log("Client activated");
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if(this.token) this.token.unsubscribe();

  }

  selectedClient?: Client;

  onSubmit(): void {

  }


}
```

What am I doing wrong, or against best practices, that is causing this not to work?

P.S. there is a stackblitz example - https://stackblitz.com/github/PhoenixStoneham/TabDataVanishing

Comment: Why do you have a router-outlet in client.component. Would it not be simpler to have them simply included as components you pass data to with @Input decorator? Your issue is the Subject is async and not available when you show your detail.

Comment: I've removed all the database code for simplicity, and I'm using that array as a placeholder for the example. Assume that the setclient method will normally go to the database asynchronously.

Comment: @E.Maggini because it's not just client details that will be in that tab group. There will also be a list of all their orders, possibly financial data, and other things. So I'm using routing to ensure that when I want to open an order for a client, I don't have to add it then.

Comment: you would not have to "add" if you already have that data in the object held in client. Just pass it in with @Input. Like this maybe? https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/passing-data-angular-components-input

Comment: @E.Maggini you may want to run the stackblitz example and look at the client component html and routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there.
The issue is that you are using Subject, instead of behavior subject.

That means that it will only get the next value after it starts listening.

So the client that was the selected one, won't have its value under client details b/c it won't emit any value.

Comment: I'll try this in the morning

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use ngrx and define a Store.

- when ever you make an api call you update the state of the store. All
  components subscribed to the property in the store would get the
  result.